# How do I plot 3D intersections of a system of inequalities using Matlab or Mathematica?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, mathematica

My question is inspired by the problem described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344045/find-the-smallest-n-for-which-there-are-real-a-1-a-2-ldots-a-n). Let us consider for example the following system of inequalities ($x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$):

- $x+y+z>0$
- $x^3+y^3+z^3<0$
- $x^5+y^5+z^5>0$

How can I plot the intesections of these areas (my hope is to be able to visualize that in a region around the origin $(0,0,0)$ not all conditions are met.

What I tried so far is illustrating the regions in 3D using the following code:

```
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(-0.1:0.01:0.1,-0.1:0.01:0.1,-0.1:0.01:0.1);
ineq1 = (X+Y+Z > 0);
ineq2 = (X.^3+Y.^3+Z.^3 < 0);
ineq3 = (X.^5+Y.^5+Z.^5 > 0);
colors = zeros(size(X))+ineq1+ineq2+ineq3;
scatter3(X(:),Y(:),Z(:),3,colors(:),'filled')
```

As a result at least I get a rough idea of the situation:

[image]

It would be nice to see a contour (line/area) where that conditions coincide.

Comment: Given that your equations are homogeneous, you can assume without loss of generality that $x+y+z=1$. This allows to work in dimension 2 instead of 3.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Will try to play with this further.

Comment: You could try Monte Carlo in the region you are interested in maybe?

Comment: It sounds interesting - especially when a nice visualization would come along with this approach. Will check this too.

Comment: The roles of $x,y,z$ are symmetric, so you might want to concentrate on visuallizing just one octant at at time.  Inequality (2) tells us that there are no solutions in the first octant (all variables nonnegative), and similarly inequality (1) implies no solutions in the opposite octant (all variables nonpositive).

Comment: Good idea to do it octant-wise - thank you!

Comment: Originally I was thinking about something going into this direction: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73962 with the exception that we have inequalities here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RegionPlot3D[x + y + z > 0 && x^3 + y^3 + z^3 > 0 && x^5 + y^5 + z^5 > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 40]
```